# Windows 10: Force IE 11 to use NonAntialiased Font

Tags: windows-10, fonts, internet-explorer, cleartype

I have an Email Client which uses Internet Explorer 11 for displaying HTML.

Is it possible to force IE 11 to use a NonAntialiased font/quality?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

IE 11 will soon be removed from Windows 10 systems, and IE cannot be changed or adapt to new uses.

Chromium Edge will nicely handle the vast majority of situations where IE 11 was needed.

(1) Can your Mail Client adapt to Chromium Edge?

(2) Can you use a different Mail Client?  The common Mail Clients use Chromium Edge (or another browser).

Comment: Thanks for replying. Firefox is my browser. My Mail-Client (or rather notifier) is POPPeeper. I like it and unfortunately it uses IE.

Comment: Check your Pop Peeper settings carefully.  I use Pop Peeper (and yes I like it). It opens links in Chromium Edge.  Look through all the settings and be sure to update it.

Comment: yes, I know you can set any browser to open links in. I'm referring to the HTML messages displayed in POP Peeper. Thank you.

Comment: My HTML messages display properly in Pop Peeper. All from a wide variety of sources.